# Behaviour of using drupal_add_js

Tags: 7, javascript

When using the drupal_add_js function, should I see the script I am loading appear in the list of scripts being loading in the header of the generated html page? I thought I should, but I don't - so perhaps my understanding of this function is wrong. Can someone clarify what is suppose to happen.

Just as note I have verified that the path to the script is correct so I know that isn't the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the code you're using?

Comment: if you have turned on javascript aggregation/optimization, then no, you won't see the individual file, but its content will be included in the file drupal builds.  it's always a good idea to clear these caches when new files are added.  of course, if you aren't doing this aggregation/optimization, then yes, they should show up.

Comment: I don't have aggregation turned on and do clear the cache every time I make a change. But my understanding is correct that it should be visible. Now I just need to figure out why it isn't working.

Comment: @user5013 please post your code

Answer (score 0):

With drupal_add_js() you can set the scope to either header or footer, specify the group the script is loaded into, and give the script a weight relative to that group. Scripts are loaded by scope > group > weight, where a lower weight will be loaded before a higher weight.

If you have aggregation turned on in /admin/config/development/performance, the script will be combined with others with the same scope & group, and ordered by weight.